# How to include javafx in my .exe file and specify the module-path (possibly using Launch4j)

Tags: eclipse, javafx, jar, exe, launch4j

i made a .exe file of my jar using launch4j, the problem is that even if i can specify the VM machine arguments that i need like:
--module-path="C:\0java\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules "javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
it will work just on my machine, so what i need is:

**-Including javafx libraries in my app when creating the runnable jar with eclipse
-Creating a .exe file that already knows the module-path of javafx and that works on every machine**

I've been searching everywhere but can't find how to do it!

Comment: See the [packaging resources in the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: if you like `launch4j` then you have option to use "bundled jre". use `jlink` to build it and distribute it along with your application (also packages `jpackage`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the JavaFX lib path that you define here ->
(`--module-path="C:\0java\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules "javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"`).

The Path ->("C:\0java\javafx-sdk-19\lib") is only correct on your computer or system because the location of JavaFX lib is not the same on all computers. That's why the exe is only working in your system.

So, bundle JavaFX lib so that it installs in the same folder where your exe is located, and then change the path of lib to -> ("javafx-sdk-19\lib").